# Google Games Service Offline

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-api-client

I am using Google Play Services to save and load my save games. This works if the device is online.
As google writes [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) it is possible to do that without beeing online. But unfortunately I get an

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

if I try to open my save game using this line:

```
result = Games.Snapshots.open(apiClient, SAVE_GAME_NAME, true).await();
```

I do not understand how I could load a save game if the **open** method needs a connected ApiClient that I obviously dont have in offline mode.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: As I read here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin Google leaves the local saving logic to the developer. Is this right? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots, Snapshots represents the player’s game progress on Google’s server; Hence, you need a server connection to use this and the file that you will load is only saved in there. When you want to load a saved game offline, there must be a local file that the app will read. I suggest that when you call commitAndClose() method save the sent data on your device’s storage. It will be possible for you to load a game offline using the said file and just read it. However, you need to use an if statement that when the user is offline it will load the local file and when the user is online it will call Snapshots.